# Trying to delete string from memory. Won't let me assign to cin

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Cfriend.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string * TempName = new std::string;
    std::cout << "Name your friend:\n";
    std::getline (std::cin, TempName);
    Cfriend * MyFriend = new Cfriend();
    return 0;
}
```

Hi, I'm new around here. I'm trying to create a simple procedure where the player can assign a name to `Cfriend`, but the problem is that it won't let me assign `cin` to `TempName`.

I want to be able to delete `TempName` from memory as soon as I'm done with it.

Comment: TempName is not a string - it is a pointer to a string.  Try: getline(cin, *TempName);

Comment: Read more about [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and what argument types it takes. I'm actually surprised your call compiles.

Comment: `TempName` is a `string*` not a `string`, so you need to dereference it.

Comment: And a general tip: In C++ use pointers as little as possible.

Comment: `std::getline` takes a reference to a string not a string pointer

Comment: also whenever you allocate dynamically you should `delete` after your finished with that data.

Comment: You should pass strings by value, there is no need to allocate them on a free store, std::string is optimized to be passed by value

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Just as a side question, is there any way to call new() _without_ pointers?

Comment: y do you need to call `new`?
whats wrong with just `std::string TempName;`?

Comment: Because I don't want to leave it in memory. It feels really sloppy.

Comment: but thats exactly what you are doing by calling `new`

Comment: Using `new` for every variable is sloppy, using raw pointers to hold the result of the `new` is **really** sloppy. [Manage your resources properly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), avoid `new` whenever possible.

Comment: But when I call new, I can delete it.

Comment: `new` will always return a pointer do a dynamically allocated data.
and if you wont `delete` it no one will, so you created a memory leek there.

Comment: Exactly, when I call new, I can delete it 2 lines later and prevent memory leaks.

Comment: You do not prevent memory leaks by using `new` and `delete` explicitly, that's very poor style. If you **must** use `new` (and your example is not a good example of somewhere that must use `new`) then use a smart pointer. The memory for a `std::string` is already created with `new[]`, and will be freed with `delete[]`, let the `string` manage it for you instead of adding another level of allocation on top.

Comment: consider this:
say you allocated with `new` at the begining of a function and `deleted` at the end, well what can happen is the function can release the flow/throw/crash before getting to the `delete` line and you got your self a leek.

Comment: @JonathanWakely So what you're saying is that I can call delete[] on strings without new()?

Comment: @RunnyBabbit **NO!** that's not what I'm saying at all! The `string` deletes _its own memory_. Stop trying to micro-manage memory. See my answer below.

Comment: @YonatanNir Sorry about that. I'm just now getting adjusted to the website's interface.

Comment: Runny Babbit: I think you were perfectly fine in accepting Jonathan's answer rather than @YonatanNir's. Jonathan's was more detailed and explained things better. Ultimately, it's up to you what to accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to use a `std::string*` where a `std::string` is expected.

The best solution is to not use `new` to create every object, C++ is not Java or C#.

```
#include "Cfriend.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string tempName;
    std::cout << "Name your friend:\n";
    std::getline (std::cin, tempName);
    Cfriend myFriend;
    return 0;
}
```

> I want to be able to delete `TempName` from memory as soon as I'm done with it.

Why? Is the name going to be thousands of bytes long?

If it's essential that it be destroyed then let the `std::string` destructor do that:

```
#include "Cfriend.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Cfriend myFriend;
    {
        std::string tempName;
        std::cout << "Name your friend:\n";
        std::getline (std::cin, tempName);
        myFriend.setName(tempName);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`tempName` goes out of scope at the closing brace and its memory is deallocated.

If you **really, really** can't re-arrange the code like this, you can still force the `string` to deallocate the memory it owns:

```
    std::string tempName;
    // ...
    tempName.clear();
    tempName.shrink_to_fit();
```

When every single commenter is telling you to stop using `new` explicitly that should be a pretty big hint to re-evaluate your assumptions about writing good C++.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of using the Cfriend constructor. Just another quick question, will that overwrite the parent constructor?

Comment: Huh? What constructor?  What parent constructor? What are you talking about?

Comment: Doesn't putting everything under Cfriend myFriend imply that it's under the constructor?

Comment: No, look at the semi-colon, it uses the `CFriend` default constructor (which you already used in your own code) and the code below it is a separate block of code that happens after the constructor.

Comment: if you mean the braces efter `CFriend` declaretion, they are only there to signal the end of scope so the string can be deleted they have nothing to do with `CFriend`

Comment: @DimaMaligin, `{}` are braces, `()` are parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

As for the destruction of `TempString`, it will be destructed once it leaves the scope.

that means you can write e.g.

```
int main()
{
    // Some code...

    {
        std::string temp;
        std::getline(std::cin, temp);

        // Do something with the string `temp`
    }
    // No `temp` string object, it doesn't exist, and has been destructed

    // More code...
}
```

The big question here, though, is *why* you would want this? Unless you expect several megabytes of input text in a single line, there is really no use of scoping for temporary variables. And if you want to redeclare the `temp` (or `TempString`) variable, why would you do that? Just reuse the existing variable.

Answer (score 0):

TempName there is a pointer to a string. Try adding a * before it for dereferencing when using it:

```
getline(std::cin, *TempName);
```

Or you can also just use a string in advance and not a pointer to it:

```
int main()
{
    std::string myString;
    std::getline(std::cin, myString);

    // Do something with the string you just read
}
```